# Reading user information from binary file to linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, structure, fread

I was trying to read the node from the binary file but it would only read the first one(i think).When load() is run it shows the following:
[Output of only load execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tamTF.jpg)

*Please note the two printf's were only to check if it it read correctly or not.It wont be there in the final version as is the scanf() statements in void save().
There purpose is simply to load and save data to file*

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

//function prototypes
struct user* newuser();
void save();
void load();
void display();


struct user
{
    char uname[50];
    char upass[15];
    int uid;
    int listofbooks[3];
    struct user *next;
};
struct user *ustart=NULL;

/*struct book
{
    int bid;
    char topic[15];
    char aut[50];
    char bname[50];
    struct book *l;
    struct book *r;
};  */

struct user* newuser()
{
  struct user *u;
  u=(struct user* )malloc(sizeof(struct user))  ;
  return(u);
};

/*void save()
{
 struct user *ul;
 struct user *t;
 int i;
 FILE *fp;

 ul=newuser();
 if(ustart==NULL)
 {
     ustart=ul;
     ul->next=NULL;

     printf("Enter Name\n");
   scanf("%s",ul->uname);
   printf("Enter Password\n");
   scanf("%s",ul->upass);
   printf("Enter ID\n");
   scanf("%d",&ul->uid);
   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
       ul->listofbooks[i]=0;
   }

   if( ( fp=fopen("ham.txt","wb+") )==NULL )
  {
      printf("FIle opening error");
      getch();
  }
   fwrite(ul,sizeof(struct user),1,fp);
   fclose(fp);
 }
 else
 {
   t=ustart;
   while(t->next!=NULL){
    t=t->next;
   }
   //change
   t->next=ul;
   ul->next=NULL;
   printf("Enter Name\n");
   scanf("%s",ul->uname);
   printf("Enter Password\n");
   scanf("%s",ul->upass);
   printf("Enter ID\n");
   scanf("%d",&ul->uid);
   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
       ul->listofbooks[i]=0;
   }

    if( ( fp=fopen("ham.txt","rb+") )==NULL )
  {
       printf("FIle opening error");
   }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

   fwrite(ul,sizeof(struct user),1,fp);
   fclose(fp);
 }
}*/



void load()
{
 int i;
 long int j;
 struct user *ul;
 FILE *fp;

 ul=newuser();
 ustart=ul;

  if( ( fp=fopen("ham.txt","rb+") )==NULL )
  {
      printf("FIle opening error");
      getch();
 }
  fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
  j=ftell(fp);
  j=( j/sizeof(struct user)) ;

   for(i=0;i<j;i++)
   {
    fseek(fp, (sizeof(struct user) * i), SEEK_SET);
    fread(ul,sizeof(struct user),1,fp);
    printf("\nName:%s",ul->uname);
    printf("\nPassword:%s",ul->upass);
    ul=ul->next;
   }

   fclose(fp);

}

void display()
{
    struct user *t;
    int i;
    t=ustart;
    while(t!=NULL)
    {
    printf("Name:%s\nPassword:%s\nID:%d\nList of books",t->uname,t->upass,t->uid);
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("%d",t->listofbooks[i]);
    }
  }
}

void main()
{
   int i,lp=1;
   do{
    printf("\n1.load\n3.exit\n2.display\n4.save\nEnter choice:");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    switch(i)
    {
        case 1: load();
        break;

    case 2:display();
    break;

    case 3:lp=0;
    printf("Exiting");
    break;

    //case 4:save();
    //break;

    default:printf("invalid");
    break;
    }
     }while(lp);

    }
```

Please help find the error in the code.I have checked many sites tried many different ways of iterating fread() but to no avail.

I don't think there's an issue with fwrite as the string members are there when i open the txt file.(void save() is in comment form as i wish to use it only to change the database/file.)

I use code:blocks.I have been using C for about a year and a half but fairly new to file functions and linked list.Any tips to improve the code ?

Comment: Review `ul = ul->next;`.  Where does `.next` value originate?  Consider `"ham.txt"` was written by another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new user every iteration of your loop while reading users from file:

Delete these lines (it is very unclear, you want to read `j` users but you allocate memory for only one):

```
ul=newuser();
ustart=ul;
```

Add these changes:

```
   user* previousUser = NULL; // to hold previous user from file

   for(i=0;i<j;i++)
   {
        ul=newuser(); // create new user with every iteration
        if (!i)
            ustart = ul; // set head of list

        fseek(fp, (sizeof(struct user) * i), SEEK_SET);
        fread(ul,sizeof(struct user),1,fp);
        printf("\nName:%s",ul->uname);
        printf("\nPassword:%s",ul->upass);

        ul->next = NULL; // set next to NULL for current user
        if (previousUser)
            previousUser->next = ul; // update previous user to point to current one
        previousUser = ul;
   }
```

Comment: Minor bits: 1) `fseek(fp, (sizeof(struct user) * i), SEEK_SET);` is strange in OP's code and  appears not needed here either.  2) `printf("\nName:%.*s",(int) sizeof ul->uname, ul->uname);` would be resilient to _null character_-less `.uname`.

Comment: Thanks a ton this is exactly what  was required. !!